# How do i align both textviews on top of the drawable preventing them to pile up on eachother

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Hello stackoverflow members. i am trying to achieve this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic0fj.jpg

But for some reason the two texts cant take these positions like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/diY7w.jpg
Could anyone explain what i am doing wrong? 
and please forgive my artistic talents.

i have added the whole xml file.

The idea is that the two textviews timer and typegekookt are displayed  in the center of backgroundtypegekookt evenly spaced out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/eggContainer"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp">


<ImageView android:id="@+id/eggtimerimage"
    android:src="@drawable/eiwit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt"
    android:src="@drawable/timerwijzer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/typegekookt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="zacht"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10:00"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/divider2"
/>

<TextView
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/divider1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eggtimerimage"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
    />
<TextView
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the ImageView `android:id="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt"`, use a RelativeLayout (or a LinearLayout) with that background (`android:background="@drawable/timerwijzer"`), and put your TextViews in it

This is what I mean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/eggContainer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eggtimerimage"
        android:src="@drawable/eiwit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundtypegekookt"
        android:background="@drawable/timerwijzer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typegekookt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="zacht"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:below="@id/typegekookt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="10:00"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- You can use 2 Views instead of 2 TextViews, more efficiently -->
    <!-- Anyway, in your screenshots I only see 1 - I guess you'll have to fix that -->
    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
    />
    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/backgroundtypegekookt"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/backgroundtypegekookt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/backgroundtypegekookt"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/backgroundtypegekookt"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also fixed the deprecated `fill_parent` to `match_parent` and `@+id` (anticipated reference) to `@id` (reference), where needed.

Also see my comments in the layout avout the 2 last views.

Comment: Thank you for the response, That fixed the issue :D. hadn't even thought about the way you approached the issue! Learned something new today.

Comment: I learn something new every day. Glad to have contributed to widen your Point Of View.